# Are questions about curating and preserving resources on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Meta Stack Exchange has a question, [Bulk Fix possible for "Old New Thing" links? Important Win32 resource](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383208/308065). My answer to this is "no, not really; it's hard, and I don't know how to":

> I've been trying to figure out how to fix these links for a while, mostly because there are links *on The Old New Thing* in all of these formats. The Internet Archive isn't entirely useful, here. I suspect it might take somebody in Microsoft to rewrite *all* of the links.

The Old New Thing is a pretty good resource for information about on-topic Microsoft Windows versions. So I've been thinking: this is probably something the people here will know about, and perhaps have a solution to.

- Could I ask "Is there a way to resolve old Old New Thing links?" on Retrocomputing?
- Would that mean *the blog itself* is on-topic?

Answer (score 2):

As far as precedent goes, we already have [data-preservation](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-preservation).  Most questions with that tag deal with preserving and recovering data on digital media at hand, but we also have a couple others that seem vaguely similar:

- [What is the optimal way to store retro computing paraphernalia (games, consoles, accessories, books) on display at home?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/7498/15334)
- [Where can I donate my old Computer Shopper Magazines to make sure they get scanned and shared?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/9411/15334)
- [Does a source exist for high-resolution PAL (not NTSC) video game cover scans?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/18283/15334)

One of them was closed as off-topic, the others were not.

Additionally, some time ago I have created [reference-request](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) to track questions about searching for specific resources or asking to recommend resources in general.  There are a number of questions already, and nobody seems to be in a rush to close them.

Personally, I don’t think I would mind that much if questions about preservation of resources in general were accepted.  Sure, it would be unusual given the name of the site alone, but so is the fact that [Latin Stack Exchange accepts Ancient Greek questions](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261/).

That said, I’m less enthusiastic about the question about *The Old New Thing* in particular.  It’s not like the answer can be much more than ‘paste the link into the Wayback Machine, if it’s not there, you’re out of luck’.  But that does not necessarily make it off-topic on its own.

(For what it’s worth, I myself had considered at one point asking a question about a decent Web version of Ralf Brown’s… until I discovered https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/, which basically fulfils almost all the criteria I had in mind.)

Comment: I was thinking of asking specifically because there _might_ be more than "try the Wayback Machine". Maybe somebody's curated a lookup table somewhere. Maybe a Microsoft employee with access to the archives stumbles across it and goes "this didn't exist, but I've just made it; help yourself!".

Comment: The cynic in me says that if Microsoft cared, they wouldn’t break the links in the first place. A third-party project à la <https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/> seems the best we can hope for, but I know of no such thing. So eh, maybe.